# Why does BufferedImage constructor throw NegativeArraySizeException exception

Tags: java

Why does the following code throws `NegativeArraySizeException` exception?

```
new BufferedImage(250 * 100, 250 * 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
```

**Output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
        at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.image.Raster.createInterleavedRaster(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Main.java:120)
```

Does it exceed some internal buffer's limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(250 * 100) * (250 * 100) * 4 = 2500000000` and the result is larger than the maximum value for `int`: `2 ** 31 - 1 = 2147483647`. [The document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR) says that the data will be in single `byte` array, so it exceeds the limit.

Comment: Is there any workaround to create such huge images?